# Sending TextFile line by line with HTTP GET method in Android

Tags: android, get

I know, this is not the best method to send a textfile to a webserver from an android device, but I can not change anything on the server side and I must to stick to this method. 
Let me explain:

The textfile is a command list. I will read the first line and sending it like this:

`http://1.2.3.4/?command=FirstLineOfTheTextfile`

The answer from the server will very simple JSON, like this:

{"OK":true} or {"OK":false}

Depending on the answer (TRUE or FALSE) I want to resend the command or to read the next line and send it on the same way:

`http://1.2.3.4/?command=SecondLineOfTheTextfile`

Doing this until the last line in the textfile.

I`ve done in the APP with followings:

1. scanning APs
2. connect to it
3. read the file
4. sending the first line
5. parsing the answer

But, I don`t know what is the best way to do this:

Send a command

Wait for the answer

if FALSE send again

if TRUE Send the next command

Wait for the answer

if FALSE send again

if TRUE Send the next command

Wait for the answer
.
.
and so on

Any suggestion is appreciated! :)

At the moment I doing like this with the first and second command:

```
public void CheckStatus() {
    TextView actualAction = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.action);
    if (filePath != "") {
        actualAction.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        actualAction.setText("Getting STATUS information...");
        sendCommand("http://1.2.3.4/?action=A"); //FIRST LINE OF THE TEXTFILE
    } else {
        actualAction.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        actualAction.setText("Choose a file first!");
    }
}

public void switchTheLightOn() {
    okStatus = false;
    TextView actualAction = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.action);
    actualAction.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
    actualAction.setText("Switching to UPDATE mode...");
    sendCommand("http://1.1.1.1/?action=on"); //SECOND LINE OF THE TEXTFILE
}
```

and when the answer parsed:

```
private Handler messageHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);

        TextView clientanswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clientanswer);

        String message = (String) msg.obj;
        try {
            JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(message);
            okStatus = mainObject.getBoolean("OK");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
        String answerText = clientAnswer.toString();
        clientanswer.setText(Html.fromHtml(answerText));
        if (okStatus) {
          switchTheLightOn()
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: What is the question in your question?

Comment: Hi, I edited the post. My question is, what is the best way to do this command-answer method, when you have 400 command in that text file. So I want to send the textfile line by line. Every line right after each other..but depending on the answer. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

What about solution, I think the easiest one is to create a simple interface `Command` which will be basic interface for all possible commands.

```
public interface Command {
    /** Get text representation for command */
    String getCommand();

    /** Get description for command */
    String getDescription();
}
```

Then you have to implement all possible commands by implementation `Command` interface.

For example CommandA:

```
public class CommandA implements Command {
    @Override
    String getCommand() {
        return "A"
    }

    @Override
    String getDescription() {
        return "Getting STATUS information...";
    }
}
```

Then initialize array of you command with appropriate items.

```
Command commands = new Command[100];
// TODO fill array
```

Then iterate over this array in order to send al this commands

```
int maxRetryCount = 3;
int actualRetryCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i< commands.size(); i++) {
    actualAction.setText(commands.get(i).getDescription());
    boolean isSuccess = sendCommand("http://1.2.3.4/?action=" + command.getCommand());
    if (!isSuccess) {
         if (actualRetryCount == maxRetryCount) {
             // exit from loop in order to avoid situation with infinitive loop
             break;
         }
         actualRetryCount++;
         --i;
    } else {
         actualRetryCount = 0;
    }

    // Do whatever you need
}
```

P.S. It is the worst client-server architecture a have ever heard.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! Don`t judge me, the webserver is untouchable. I can communicate with it only in this way.

Comment: However one thing what I don`t understand. the sendCommand sends the command and the isSuccess will be true always, except when the server is not online. BUT the next step must depend on the answer from the server. If is TRUE then send the next command, if is FALSE then retry... the sendCommand opens a httpurlconnection, the answer is recovered from the inputstrem and sets the okStatus variable.

Comment: SendCommand should return answer from server in this implementation

Comment: @TheSaint, did my answer help you?

Comment: Hi, hopefully, I did not have chance to work on it until now...I will let you know soon.